# How to count years in the text in R?

Tags: r, stringr, strsplit

I want to count years found between the opening and closing brackets in the following text named `txt`.

```
library(stringr)
txt <- "Text Mining exercise (2020) Mining, p. 628508; Computer Science text analysis (1998) Computer Science, p.345-355; Introduction to data mining (2015) J. Data Science, pp. 31-33"
```

`lengths(strsplit(txt,"\\(\\d{4}\\)"))` gives me `4` which is wrong. Any help, please?

Comment: You mean within (parentheses) and not within [brackets]?

Comment: @sindri_baldur `(  )` are commonly referred to as brackets. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `stringr::str_count()`:

```
str_count(txt, "\\([0-9]{4}\\)")
[1] 3
```

To include only number of four digits within parentheses that also start with 1 or 2 followed by either 0 or 9:

```
str_count(txt, "\\([1-2][0|9][0-9]{2}\\)")
```

Strictly starting with either 19 or 20:

```
str_count(txt, "\\(19[0-9]{2}\\)|\\(20[0-9]{2}\\)")
# In R 4.0
str_count(txt, r"(\(19[0-9]{2}\)|\(20[0-9]{2}\))")
```

Comment: Thank you. Is that possible to enforce the code to consider the first two digits of the year in the brackets should begin with `19` or `20`? The other two digits can be any number.

Comment: I come to you once again. I want to consider years with or without opening and closing parentheses like `(2020)` or `2020`. Given that the code `str_count(txt, "\\(19[0-9]{2}\\)|\\(20[0-9]{2}\\)")` is right to consider `(2020)`, how this line of code is updated consider a year without parentheses as well?

Comment: @Gadaa Just remove `\\(` and `\\)` from the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str_extract_all` with positive lookahead and lookbehind regex.

```
stringr::str_extract_all(txt, '(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\))')[[1]]
#[1] "2020" "1998" "2015"
```

If you want to count how many are present use `length` over it.

```
length(stringr::str_extract_all(txt, '(?<=\\()\\d+(?=\\))')[[1]])
#[1] 3
```

Probably, using `str_match_all` is easier

```
stringr::str_match_all(txt, '\\((\\d+)\\)')[[1]][, 2]
#[1] "2020" "1998" "2015"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer Base-R

```
regmatches(txt, gregexpr("[^0-9]\\d{4}[^0-9]", txt))
```

gives

```
[[1]]
[1] "(2020)" "(1998)" "(2015)"
```

and if we wrap it in `lengths( ... )` We will get the correct answer

Edit: or if you really only want the count we can shorten to

```
lengths(gregexpr("[^0-9]\\d{4}[^0-9]", txt))
```